# Only add if not null

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to set a text box in a form to display the total of a range of other text boxes. If there are no values, I want the box empty, but any value needs to display, even if only one of the contributing sources has a value.

Lets say there are three contributing boxes: `txtScore1`, `txtScore2` and `txtScore3`, and the sum box `txtTotal`. Before data appears in any of the score boxes, they contain a null value. So I've tried setting `txtTotal`'s control source to:

```
=Iif(Not IsNull([txtScore1]),[txtScore1])+
Iif(Not IsNull([txtScore2]),[txtScore2])+
Iif(Not IsNull([txtScore3]),[txtScore3])
```

But this only gives a value if all three have values, as anything + Null = Null. If I add a FalsePart of 0 to them, the value in `txtTotal` is *always* 0, even if all three are empty. Do I *have* to add a `Iif(IsNull([txtScore1]) and IsNull([txtScore2]) and IsNull([txtScore3]),null,...` before this whole thing, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NZ` function can handle this situation, assuming you can use it:

```
=Iif(IsNull([txtScore1]) AND IsNull([txtScore2]) AND IsNull([txtScore3]),
     NULL,
     Nz([txtScore1], 0) + Nz([txtScore2], 0) + Nz([txtScore3], 0))
```

`Nz` is the Access version of the standard `COALESCE` function, which uses the second parameter as a value should the first parameter be `NULL`.  Check the [Tech On The Net](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php) page for some examples of how to use it.

Comment: But if all of the score boxes are empty I *want* a null value. If I use `nz` like that I'll always get a number...

Comment: @IsaacReefman I just realized I think I answered a VBA question for you earlier today.  Check my updated answer above.  If all three are `NULL` it reports `NULL`, otherwise it reports the sum of the three, ignoring any `NULL` values.

Comment: You did, and thanks for that one. Looks like the cumbersome opening `Iif` *is* necessary, then, though using `nz` will at least shorten the following bit.

Comment: The thing is, your requirement to display `NULL` if all three are `NULL` can really only be done by checking all three values, hence the ugliness of the code.

Comment: Ooh - turns out `nz` as an expression directly in the property sheet is context savvy - `Nz([txtScore1])` (if `txtScore1.Value` is `Null`)will return 0 in that context already; the `, 0` isn't necessary!

Comment: yeah, I was hoping I could tell it to default to Null, and only un-Null if one or more of the source boxes contained a value. I was afraid it might not work, but was hoping someone had a cool solution. `nz` certainly helps!